# Prevent submit form with ENTER jquery not working with alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events

I have a form with a text input.

I managed to prevent ENTER from submitting the form by doing this:

```
jQuery("#inputTags").keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == '13') {
         event.preventDefault();

         tagManagerCreate(true);

         return false;
      }
    });
```

tagManagerCreate() does some stuff. Sometimes, this function triggers a javascript "alert".
For some reason when that happens, the form still gets submitted!

Comment: For design purposes I changed to the jQuery-UI dialog, and it fixed it. But I guess the question is still relevant for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `.keypress` instead of `.keydown`

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

and what the tagManagerCreate(true); do?

Comment: I think that was it. I'll test again with alert (since i removed it) and let you know. tagManagerCreate makes an ajax calls and sometimes triggers an alert based on the result

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to wrap `tagManagerCreate(true);` in a try/catch block and see?

```
try{

   tagManagerCreate(true);

}catch(e){}
```